# Mean Absolute Error calculation

Tags: statistics

The MAE formula is stated as the following:
$
 \mathrm {MAE} = 
 {\frac 
  {\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left| y_{i} - \hat{y}_{i} \right|} 
  {n}
 } 
$

Now I'm unsure whether you're able to sum up all $y_i$ values and $\hat{y}_i$ values and then subtract the $\hat{y}_i$ values from the $y_i$ values. Or if you immediately get the absolute value from each $\hat{y}_i$ value subtracted from the $y_i$ and then sum those up, thereafter divide those numbers by n.

When using online MAE calculators, it seems to be the latter, however I think it's supposed to be the former.

For example: imagine actual values being [2,2,3,3] and predicted values being [3,3,2,2]. Online Calculators will tell you the MAE is 0, whilst I think it's supposed to be 1, and now I'm doubting whether I am able to read formulas or not. Can anyone verify which is correct?

Comment: I think the mean absolute error here is indeed $1$. The mean error is $0$. Can you [edit] the question to show us more about the calculator?

Comment: $1$ would be the answer in your example.  https://www.mymathtables.com/calculator/stats/MAD-MAE-calculator.html looks wrong for MAE

Comment: @EthanBolker I do not know how the online calculator has calculated it, it was a plug the actual values and predicted values in the boxes and get the result from it kind of thing.

Comment: @Henry That's one of the calculators I tried, but for example the one on this website: https://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/mean-absolute-error.php, also says it's 0... So now I'm not sure whether my calculation is correct or not.

Comment: Those two calculators seem to take the two averages and report mean of actual values minus mean of predicted values (signed).  This is not an MAE measure, but might be a bias meeasure